# Apply two background colors to a text box.

Tags: css

I have a text box which I want to apply a background colour to.  Whilst I understand how to apply one background colour, I want to know what css I could apply one colour to 75% of the box and 25% of the box to another.

Comment: Do you mean a [gradient](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/linear-gradient)?

Answer (score 2):

The best way to do it would be to use gradients.

http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Answer (score 0):

Here is the [Solution](http://jsfiddle.net/6Zenu/1/).

The HTML:

```
<div class="dualColor">&nbsp;</div>
<div>&nbsp</div>
<input class="dualColor" type="text" />
```

The CSS:

```
.dualColor{background: #1dff00; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #1dff00 0%, #1dff00 75%, #ff0004 75%, #ff0004 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#1dff00), color-stop(75%,#1dff00), color-stop(75%,#ff0004), color-stop(100%,#ff0004)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #1dff00 0%,#1dff00 75%,#ff0004 75%,#ff0004 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  #1dff00 0%,#1dff00 75%,#ff0004 75%,#ff0004 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  #1dff00 0%,#1dff00 75%,#ff0004 75%,#ff0004 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to right,  #1dff00 0%,#1dff00 75%,#ff0004 75%,#ff0004 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#1dff00', endColorstr='#ff0004',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
height:20px; width:200px; border:none;
}
```

**EDIT**

You can apply dual colors to both the Div and the Text boxes.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use box-shadow for that:
[check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hJWmb/2/)

For vertical:

```
.text{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px #000 inset, 0 -5px #000 inset;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
}
```

For horizontal:

```
.text2{
    width: 100px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 25px 0 #999 inset, -75px 0 #444 inset;
    background: transparent;
    border: 0;
}
```

Note that you can't use percentage for box shadow, so this method only works with fixed width/height if you need percentage like values.

Answer (score 0):

if you not want use css3 multiple bg,
you can insert a new div in your container, who go under the content with the good bg color

on the container :

```
position:relative;
background:purple; /* primary color */
```

on the second background div :

```
position:absolute;
/* pos and size into the container */
left:20%;
top:20%;
width:60%;
height:60%;
background:yellow; /* secondary color */
```

and your initial content must be wrapped, the wrap get :

```
position:relative;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/r043v/T7gyx/